# Discord.py react to bot own messages

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to react to my bot own messages. But it does not work.

```
    if args[0] == "solido":
        reaction = ""
        sent = await ctx.message.channel.send(client.get_channel("795387716967333889"), embed=embed)
       # await message.add_reaction(sent, emoji = "\U0001F44D")
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(reaction)
```

if I use this type of code, the bot will react to MY message commands. But if i dont use the ctx method the bot will give me this error: `NameError: name 'message' is not defined`

How could I fix?

Comment: You want your bot to react under its message and not yours?

Comment: Yes, i want the bot react to its message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `await sent.add_reaction(reaction)` instead of `await ctx.message.add_reaction(reaction)` should work